# Copying C++ object to heap using assignment causes segfault on virtual function call

Tags: c++, virtual-functions

I have a C++ class with a virtual function. If I copy it using `=` to memory that I have malloc'd, and then call a virtual function, I get a segmentation fault.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Greeter {
public:
    virtual void print_hi() {
        std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;
    }
    void print_bye() {
        std::cout << "bye" << std::endl;
    }
};


int main() {
    Greeter* greeters = (Greeter*) malloc(sizeof(Greeter) * 16);

    Greeter g;
    greeters[0] = g;
    greeters[0].print_bye(); // prints "bye"
    greeters[0].print_hi(); // segmentation fault
}
```

I expected that using the assignment operator `=` would copy `g` into `greeters[0]`, and that my virtual function call would work normally. It seems instead that something related to virtual function pointers has gotten mangled. Normal methods, such as `print_bye()`, still work, though.

If you're curious why: I'm playing with optimizing some of my code for data locality (caching) by storing a contiguous array of objects, as opposed to an array of pointers to objects that are independently heap-allocated, and might not be tightly packed. Also, some of this code I'm using with CUDA, which is why I'm using `malloc` (or `cudaMalloc`) instead of `std::vector`.

I can fix this by:

1. using a stack-allocated array

```
Greeter greeters[16]; // instead of the malloc line
```

2. using placement new

```
Greeter* g = new(&greeters[0]) Greeter();
g->print_hi();
```

3. using memcpy

```
Greeter g;
memcpy(&greeters[0], &g, sizeof(Greeter));
greeters[0].print_hi();
```

Why do these approaches work, but the assignment operator does not?

Comment: Whichever C++ textbook you learned to use `malloc` in C++: you need to immediately, without delay, throw it away, shred it, burn it, and feed it to crocodiles, then get a better C++ textbook that actually teaches proper C++. That's the reason for your segfault: a fundamentally flawed C++ textbook that should've never seen the light of day. Every use of `malloc` to create an actual C++ object,  that's not a POD, without exception, is fundamentally broken, and won't work. It's quite regretful to see anyone waste their time reading from flawed C++ learning materials.

Comment: P.S. memcpy won't work either. memcpy never works, correctly, with non-POD C++ objects too.

Comment: 1 and 2 work because that is a proper way to create an object in C++. 3 using `memcpy` does not work, it is just a coincidence you get expected output.

Comment: *"a C++ class [...] memory that I have malloc'd"* -- I got this far into your question and already knew you had a disaster on your hands. Let me see if I can find a duplicate.

Comment: `malloc()` does not work well with C++ class types that have virtual functions and/or non-trivial constructors, and the resul;t (on using the object) is undefined behaviour.   Your first fix works because the semantics of initialising arrays work that way.  Your second way is emulating what a `new` expression would be doing behind the scenes if it used `malloc()` to allocate raw memory and then initialise it using a constructor.    Your approach using `memcpy()` also has undefined behaviour - a nasty feature of undefined behaviour is that "seems to work" is a valid outcome.

Comment: Good to know that `malloc` is an awful idea in C++. This is coming not from any textbook, but from me attemping to avoid using `new` in CUDA device code. I'm calling `cudaMallocManaged` on the host to allocate memory for an array of objects, and then attempting to populate it the device. (Objects with virtual functions have to be created on the device because otherwise their vtable pointers still refer to the host.)

Comment: @JaMiT Yeah, I think that one covers it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fundamental problem is that `greeters` are never properly constructed, and therefore *cannot be assigned later* and just be assumed it will work.
(Specifically the `v-table` will contain garbage.)

**This is because `malloc` doesn't construct, while `new` does. (and other alternatives may also if you are lucky.)**

This is particularly confusing in this case because objects with virtual functions have a "hidden" state even if the class looks empty **and** assignment doesn't need to override this state because the class has no members.

Using `new` is the right thing to do, and the program then works.

```
#include <iostream>

class Greeter {
public:
    virtual void print_hi() {
        std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;
    }
    void print_bye() {
        std::cout << "bye" << std::endl;
    }
};


int main() {
    Greeter* greeters = new Greeter[16];

    Greeter g;
    greeters[0] = g;
    greeters[0].print_bye(); // prints "bye"
    greeters[0].print_hi();

    delete[] greeters;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/ejr4z4f1W

To illustrate the point further, although using `malloc` is a terrible idea, the real problem is the lack of construction which in this case explicitly illustrated:

```
int main() {
    std::allocator<Greeter> alloc;

    Greeter* greeters = alloc.allocate(16);
    for(auto p = greeters; p != greeters + 16; ++p){
        alloc.construct(p);  // comment this and you will get a seg fault too
    }

    Greeter g;
    greeters[0] = g;
    greeters[0].print_bye(); // prints "bye"
    greeters[0].print_hi();

    for(auto p = greeters; p != greeters + 16; ++p){
        alloc.destroy(p);
    }

    alloc.deallocate(greeters, 16);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/qW4feqxsj

*Now, burn that book!*